# How do i send context through express redirect method in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, express

Currently, I am redirecting to a specific route of Reactjs using express's Redirect method from server.js.

Server.js :

```
 import express from 'express';
 app.get('/dashboard', (req, res) => {  
      res.redirect(req.query.redirect_uri);
      res.end();
    });
 });
```

I have to pass context while redirecting to specific route. 
and access that context from reactjs Component. How can I do this?

Comment: You can attach the context to the `res` object and access that in your `react` app to set the context. You can't set context directly from express.

Comment: @Saqib Yes but how? you mean res.redirect(req.query.redirect_uri , context);

Comment: Since you are using reactJs which is a frontend framework you should look at client side rendering. If you still want to stick with server side rendering then instead of ReactJs use some templating engine like ejs, pug or jade.

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot add a JSON payload to a redirect, you have to pass the context via URL parameters to your `redirect_uri`.

Inside your React component, you can read those URL parameters and construct your context based on that.